# How to set image.Source via async stream in an UWP application?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to set image.Source via async stream in an UWP application. Otherwise the image will flicker when switch to other image source.
My code is as below. And the log shows it works. Certainly I put 2 image files in the corresponding path before I test the demo code.
But in fact I did not see any picture shown, why?

Log:

```
111111111111 image file path = C:\Users\tomxu\AppData\Local\Packages\a0ca0192-f41a-43ca-a3eb-f128a29b00c6_1qkk468v8nmy0\LocalState\2.jpg
22222222222
33333333333333
4444444444444
The thread 0x6d38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6a34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
111111111111 image file path = C:\Users\tomxu\AppData\Local\Packages\a0ca0192-f41a-43ca-a3eb-f128a29b00c6_1qkk468v8nmy0\LocalState\1.jpg
22222222222
33333333333333
4444444444444
```

Code:

```
        private async void setImageSource(string imageFilePath)
        {
            StorageFile sFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(imageFilePath);
            Debug.WriteLine("111111111111 image file path = " + imageFilePath);
            Stream fileStream = await sFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("22222222222");
            InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            Debug.WriteLine("33333333333333");
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ras.AsStreamForRead());
            Debug.WriteLine("4444444444444");
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(ras);
            image1.Source = bi;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fullFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

            if (count % 2 == 1)
            {
                setImageSource(fullFolder + @"\1.jpg");
                //image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg"));
            }
            else
            {
                setImageSource(fullFolder + @"\2.jpg");
                //image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/2.jpg"));
            }

            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I convert a base64 image string to a BitmapImage..

```
var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
ims.Seek(0);
var img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetSource(ims);
ims.Dispose();
return img;
```

Try some of the things I'm doing there. Like I notice your code is not setting the seek of the `InMemoryReadAccessStream`

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I have something to clarify with you.

1. Your pictures are always in the application data folder. If you want to show it at runtime by programming, the easy way is using the [ms-appdata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#ms-appdata) URI scheme to refer to files that come from the app's local, roaming, and temporary data folders. Then, you could use this URL to initialize the `BitmapImage` object. With this way, you don't need to manually manipulate the file stream.

```
private void setImageSource(int i)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/"+i+".png"));
    image1.Source = bi;
}

private int count = 0;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (count % 2 == 1)
    {
        setImageSource(1);
    }
    else
    {
        setImageSource(2);
    }
    count++;
}
```

2. If you say you have to manipulate the file stream to initialize the BitmaImage, then please add some break points to debug your code. If you add break points to check the `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` after call `CopyToAsync` method, you will see that its size is 0. It meant that the file stream has not been wrote to it. To solve this issue, you need to set a buffer size for it. **Note:** you used `ras.AsStreamForRead()` method, it's incorrect. You're writing stream to it, so you need to call `ras.AsStreamForWrite()`.

The code looks like the following:

```
private async void setImageSource(string imageFilePath)
{
    StorageFile sFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(imageFilePath);

    using (Stream fileStream = await sFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ras.AsStreamForWrite((int)fileStream.Length));
            ras.Seek(0);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(ras);
            img.Source = bi;
        }
    }
}

private int count = 0;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string fullFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
    if (count % 2 == 1)
    {
        setImageSource(fullFolder + @"\1.jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        setImageSource(fullFolder + @"\2.jpg");
    }
    count++;
}
```

In addition, like @visc said, you need to call `ras.Seek(0)` method to reset the stream to beginning, else the image will not show there.